# Gravity Forms - Get Current Page Number

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I have a multi-page form.

I would like to execute some custom JavaScript on the last page of this form. Theoretically, all I have to do is retrieve the current page number and write a conditional.

**Simple, right?** Apparently not.

My original workaround was like this:

```js
if ($('gform_page').last().css('display') !== 'none') {
    // perform custom scripts now that the last
    // Gravity Form page is being shown
}
```

but `$('...').css('display')` returns `undefined` on *every* element I've tried this on within the form. Custom scripts were being fired every time the user hit the "Next" button. No cigar.

Then, after reviewing [the Gravity Forms documentation](http://gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Developer_Docs), I found two useful-looking events: `gform_post_render` and `gform_page_loaded`.

However, the documentation gives no instruction on how to access the parameters.

```js
jQuery(document).bind('gform_page_loaded', function(event, form_id, current_page){
    console.log(current_page);
    // returns nothing when loaded in the footer
    // returns [Object, object] when placed in an HTML field in the form
});
```

In addition to not having the correct code, I also suspect I don't have the code in the correct place as I have also fruitlessly tried the following in functions.php and in header.php ([as the documentation suggests](http://gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_enqueue_scripts)):

```php
<?php
function enqueue_custom_script($form, $is_ajax){
    if ($is_ajax) :
        echo '<script>console.log(current_page);</script>';
    endif;
}
add_action("gform_enqueue_scripts", "enqueue_custom_script", 10, 2);
?>
```

## Question:

What code do I need to retrieve the current page number, and more importantly, where do I place that code?

Comment: That's not what closing a question is for. Questions get closed when they are off-topic or not answerable because of missing information. It's a sign that something is wrong with the question. If you don't want to interact with the question anymore, it's fine to just ignore it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it.

The function [`rgpost`](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Rgpost/) is, apparently, crucial in accessing the current page number. After some muddling around on my own, I was able to get the following code working in both functions.php and just before the wp_head() function in header.php.

```php
function run_script_on_last_page($form) {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        $current_page = rgpost('gform_source_page_number_' . $form['id']) ? rgpost('gform_source_page_number_' . $form['id']) : 1;
        if ($current_page == 10) {
            wp_enqueue_script('custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
        }
    }
}
add_action('gform_enqueue_scripts_63', 'run_script_on_last_page');
```

If you're copy/pasting the code above, make sure to:

- replace `10` with the page you want to check
- ensure your parameters are correct in `wp_enqueue_script`
- replace `63` with your form ID

Some resources I found useful:

- [this section](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Using_the_Gravity_Forms_%22gform_validation%22_Hook#Getting_the_Current_Page) of the documentation for the `gform_validation` filter
- the documentation for [`gform_enqueue_scripts`](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_enqueue_scripts).

Comment: I actually think McNab's answer above is a better one. :)

Comment: This doesn't work correctly if someone clicks the previous button then clicks next again, the page numbers get off by 1.

Answer (score 8):

The OPs accepted answer might well work but it doesn't work if you have the form setup to paginate using Ajax.

In that case I could only get it working using Javascript and the following method;

http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_post_render

```
jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function (event, formId, current_page) {
    if (current_page == 2) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

You could of course use the `formId` parameter to limit this to a specific form

Comment: Can I redirect user to direct last page ? what would be last page URL ?

Answer (score 2):

The currently accepted answer only works if the user never goes to a previous page in the form, if they do, then `gform_sourge_page_number` always lags by one. I found a better solution (using this hook for an example, but you should be able to use it within any hook that has the $form passed to it):

```
function run_script_on_last_page( $form)  {
  if ( !is_admin() ) {
    if ( \GFFormDisplay::get_current_page( $form['id'] ) == 10) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
    }
  }
}

add_action( 'gform_enqueue_scripts_63', 'run_script_on_last_page' );
```

`GFFormDisplay::get_current_page( $form_id )` is one of many handy undocumented functions.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little function that returns the current page:

```
// Get Gravity Forms Current Page
// Syntax: gf_current_page()
function gf_get_current_page()
{
    return rgpost('gform_source_page_number_' . $_POST['gform_submit']) ? rgpost('gform_target_page_number_' . $_POST['gform_submit']) : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to the accepted answer, here is an example of finding the current page, and dynamically finding how many pages are in the form. This example changes button text based on whether it is the last page of the form, instead of enqueueing a script.

```
// Change the text of the 'Next' form button to 'Submit' when
// the current page is the final page of the form
add_filter( 'gform_next_button', 'next_to_submit', 10, 2 );
function next_to_submit( $next_button, $form ) {
    $replacement_next_button = $next_button;
    $last_page_number = 1;
    foreach ($form['fields'] as $field) {
        $is_hidden = RGFormsModel::is_field_hidden( $form, $field, array() );
        if ($field['pageNumber'] > $last_page_number && !$is_hidden) {
            $last_page_number = $field['pageNumber'];
        }
    }
    $current_page_number = rgpost('gform_source_page_number_' . $form['id']) ? rgpost('gform_source_page_number_' . $form['id']) : 1;
    if ($last_page_number === $current_page_number) {
        // If the current page is the final page
        $replacement_next_button = str_replace( 'Next', 'Submit', $next_button );
    }
    return $replacement_next_button;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me in JavaScript:

```
$('.gf_step_active .gf_step_number').html()
```

It will give you the page number of the current page in multi-page form.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery

```
  var current_page_ = 1+parseInt(jQuery('.gform_page:visible').index());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one:

```
var current_visible_page = jQuery('.gf_step_active .gf_step_number').html();
console.log(current_visible_page);
```

Use the above method in the console to check how it's working.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer in PHP.

You can use the `GFFormDisplay` class to also get the current page in PHP.

Example:

`\GFFormDisplay::get_current_page({$form_id})`

Information retrieved from the Gravity Forms plugin (line 652).

If you want more information about the `GFFormDisplay` class, check below:
https://github.com/wp-premium/gravityforms/blob/master/form_display.php